# How to show error message when my server is down / not available while making JQuery request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, richfaces, ajax4jsf

I have a code something goes like this;

```
<a4j:commandLink   
actionListener="#{controller.validate}"  
onclick="showFadeLoadingImg();"  
oncomplete="confirmOperation();}"  
value="#{actionItem.actionDisplayName}"  
reRender="text1,text2">  
</a4j:commandLink>
```

Here, when my server is down, my oncomplete event has jscript function confirmOperation(), which gets executed and undesired output from that function is being displayed. But, what I ultimately want is, when I click the button, I want to check whether I can able to connect to the server, and if not I have to show some error message like 'Unable to reach server' . Can you give me code example of achieving this?

Comment: You mean an Ajax request?

Comment: Why exactly did you tag jQuery? RichFaces 3.x doesn't use jQuery under the covers. Only RichFaces 4.x does. The presence of `reRender` attribute implies 3.x (this has been renamed to `render` in 4.x). RichFaces 3.x uses Prototype.js under the covers. The JSF code posted so far doesn't seem to use jQuery anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Create an Ajax request like-

```
var jqAjax =   $.ajax({
                                           url:  'server URL',
                                           type: "GET/POST",
                                           dataType: "TYPE" , 
                                           });
```

then,  implement

```
jqAjax.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
  //Check the textStatus
});
```

Check the `textStatus`, for values - `0, 404, 500, timeout, abort, parsererror`